# MicroProfile JWT with multiple public keys

Tags: java, security, jwt, quarkus, microprofile

I want to secure a REST API via JWTs provided as Authorization Header in the requests. I am have a quarkus application and would like to use their official guide - https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jwt

The guide specifies:

```
mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location=publicKey.pem 
mp.jwt.verify.issuer=https://example.com/issuer
```

So far so good, now we can check if JWTs are signed by a private key that corresponds to this public key. The problem I have is that I have different APIs and different OAuth integrations, let's say 3. So different API Endpoints expect different JWTs and hence also have different public keys. Is this even supported in mp?

Spring Security allows multiple WebSecurity with different @Order and integrating multiple oAuth Servers works there. How can this be done in Quarkus/MP JAX-RS?

Comment: I ended up using import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter. I differentiate between what I want to Authenticate via custom Annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But using a [JSON Jwt Key Set](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7517#section-2):

```
mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location=my-pubkeys.json
```

The Jwt Ket Set allows to provide several public keys in row. You can also provide an URL instead.

Also, forget about `mp.jwt.verify.issuer`: the property expects a string representing a single issuer. This property is not mandatory, so if you really want to control the issuer you will have to control it by yourself in your request filter.

If you only have PEM files for your pubkeys, you can turn them into Jwt Key Set using PEM to JWT convertor like [this one (online)](https://8gwifi.org/jwkconvertfunctions.jsp). Then you just have to serve the .json file.